# Concrete5 google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How do i get google analytics to work

I've put it in site/settings - tracking code.
I made a google analytics account but it says 0 visited

Hope you guys can help

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes one day before you will see the result in Google Analytics. It is not real time... If you placed the tracking code on your website you should be good to go.

Place the following script immediatly after your `<body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<<Your UA-000909 ID>>']); 
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 
</script>
```

Place the following script immediately before your `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  (function() { 
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga); 
  })(); 
</script>
```

Between the scripts your content should be. This gives the best page load time.

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether Google Analytics is configured correctly immediately after setup by utilizing the Google Analytics realtime view. In one browser tab visit your website, in another tab have Google Analytics open, with the real time tab selected (it can be found on the left hand side of the Google Analytics user interface under the reporting tab).

To install, grab your tracking code (it sounds like you've already done this) and paste before the closing  tag.

You can also test whether you've configured Google Analytics correctly by selecting *admin*, then *tracking info*, then *tracking code*. If configured correctly, you should see the Status as "Status: Receiving Data".